# What settings to use when installing MinGW-W64 to build FuTTY?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I want to build [FuTTY](https://github.com/FireEgl/FuTTY).

The original author uses Visual Studio, I want to avoid that. I found out that apparently I have to:

- Add `MinGW/bin` and `MinGW/msys/1.0/bin` to the PATH
- run `perl mkfiles.pl`to restore some missing makefiles
- Remove `-mno-cygwin` from Makefile.cyg
- Add `XFLAGS = -DCOVERITY` to Makefile.cyg
- run `make -f Makefile.cyg putty.exe` from the `windows` directory

This works for building [the original PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), but is not enough for FuTTY.

It complains that `KEY_WOW64_32KEY` is undeclared. When I googled that, I found that apparently [this means you need MinGW-W64](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-apps/2013-07/msg00206.html).

At this point I'm making wild guesses, but I think the selector shown below means that the MinGW-W64 project is about making all kinds of toolchains run on Windows 64 bit and if I want something that works with PuTTY's MinGW makefile, I need this:

[image: MinGW-W64 download selector]

Right? So after downloading that, I am presented with questions I cannot answer:

[image: MinGW-W64 install dialog]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using more handy tool chain distribution [MSYS2](https://msys2.github.io)